# Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to craete google map project. I have imported the google-play-service lib and enabled the Google Maps Android API 2 as well created android API key. After  editing my manifest.xml I am getting the error below:

**Error**

```
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988): Process: com.example.map, PID: 13988
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.map/com.example.map.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2760)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:770)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:366)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at com.example.map.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    ... 10 more
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.fk.a(Unknown Source)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.a.g.a(Unknown Source)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(Unknown Source)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(Unknown Source)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.i.onTransact(SourceFile:62)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzc$zza$zza.zzr(Unknown Source)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zzvu(Unknown Source)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onInflate(Unknown Source)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2169)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:300)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:838)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.callActivityOnCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:34)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:826)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:732)
07-05 10:21:43.525: E/AndroidRuntime(13988):    ... 19 more
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.map"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

  <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
                <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="TIzaSyDS5wem-JxFUXnw8uVNljCNlm4NRwGAZQs" />

        <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

**MainActivity: **

```
package com.example.map;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add your map API KEY to your `manifest.xml`:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="TIzaSyDS5wem-JxFUXnw8uVNljCNlm4NRwGAZQs" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: This value here `TIzaSyDS5wem-JxFUXnw8uVNljCNlm4NRwGAZQs` is my aip key. then I have to replace it with `"YOUR_MAP_API_KEY"`